# MonoTouch CurrentUICulture

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, cultureinfo, nslocale

When I change the Language of the emulator or the device this change is not reflected in neither `Thread.CurrentUICulture` nor `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`. Is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently there is not glue between `CultureInfo` and `NSLocale`. I'm not sure we can have an exact match between the two (different lists) and, even on match, there would be small subtle differences that could cause trouble when porting code.

However it could be worth investigating adding a MonoTouch-specific `CultureInfo` that would use the current `NSLocale` settings. If you think this would solve your problem then please fill a bug report (priority Enhancement) to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so it can be priorized for future releases.

I had to make a similar *fix* to allow .NET `TimeZoneInfo` to work properly on devices (that will be available in MonoTouch 5.2 and 5.1 betas).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I'm doing my own mapping from NSLocale to a self-maintained CultureInfo for the time being.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold any chance of publishing your own mapping on Github or the like?

Comment: Has this been fixed? Because it's a pain when working with cross plattform libraries.